# googlevoice will not programmatically login (Python)

Tags: python, authentication, google-voice

I am getting the following error traceback when my program tries to login to GoogleVoice (`from googlevoice import Voice, util`) to send SMS message.

```
    File "C:\Users\ble1usb\Dropbox\Git\ers-dataanalyzzer\MainFrame.py", line 38, in call_mainframe
    ah.compare_status() # compares current status with historical status. alerts alarm team if necessary
  File "C:\Users\ble1usb\Dropbox\Git\ers-dataanalyzzer\alarm_handler.py", line 61, in compare_status
    self.megaphone = megaphone.MegaPhone()     # Am I going to have problems putting this here? I am getting relentless login fails due to the shitty googlevoice login
  File "C:\Users\ble1usb\Dropbox\Git\ers-dataanalyzzer\megaphone.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.voice.login(bl_google_credentials[0], bl_google_credentials[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googlevoice\voice.py", line 70, in login
    galx = re.search(r"name=\"GALX\"\s+value=\"(.+)\"", content).group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My program has been running successfully for the last several weeks. Every once in a while, the above error would get thrown and the error handling would just try again. Now, it has not had a successful login in several hundred tries.

One issue that I feel may be important is that the program was logging in every ten (10) minutes regardless of whether or not an SMS was sent (rare case, every few days at most).

In the above traceback, You can see that I moved the function call that performed the GoogleVoice login to within the loop only in case its needed. It is still having problems because there is an alarm notification that needs to be sent out.

I tried logging in and out of my Google account, no avail.

Here's a clue --> the following code was copied out of the file identified in the last line of the traceback (source of error):

```
def login(self, email=None, passwd=None):
        """
        Login to the service using your Google Voice account
        Credentials will be prompted for if not given as args or in the ``~/.gvoice`` config file
        """
        if hasattr(self, '_special') and getattr(self, '_special'):
            return self

    if email is None:
        email = config.email
    if email is None:
        email = input('Email address: ')

    if passwd is None:
        passwd = config.password
    if passwd is None:
        from getpass import getpass
        passwd = getpass()

    content = self.__do_page('login').read()
    # holy hackjob
    galx = re.search(r"name=\"GALX\"\s+value=\"(.+)\"", content).group(1)
    self.__do_page('login', {'Email': email, 'Passwd': passwd, 'GALX': galx})

    del email, passwd

    try:
        assert self.special
    except (AssertionError, AttributeError):
        raise LoginError

    return self
```

We should note that

`galx = re.search(r"name=\"GALX\"\s+value=\"(.+)\"", content).group(1)`

is the source of the error and that (this is important) the line immediately above it says

`# holy hackjob`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to correct the issue. It appears that Google did make a modification:

The patch is here: http://pastebin.com/bxvNjj00

Or you can simply modify voice.py and change the offending line that begins with galx = to this:

galx = re.search(r"name=\"GALX\" type=\"hidden\"\n *value=\"(.+)\"", content).group(1)

Comment: That fixed it. How in the world would one know that? Any chance you could provide insight to what is going on in that line?

Comment: I simply inspected the variable called content by writing it out to a plain text file. I searched that file for name="GALX" and discovered that Google had added type="hidden", a carriage return, and 11 spaces before the value=. I simply modified the RegEx to match the new code and viola!

Comment: "I feel like the fact that the inclusion "Holy hackjob" in Google's code is a big clue" Just for your edification. pygooglevoice is not Google's code. It is written by a third party as a binding to the GV service.

Comment: It appears that the pygooglevoice community is pretty quick also: https://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/issues/detail?id=76&q=galx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very well versed in regex, so I rewrote mine to dice up the string. In case the new modification breaks in the future, a try except statement can be used like this:

```
    try:
        galx = re.search(r"name=\"GALX\" type=\"hidden\"\n *value=\"(.+)\"", content).group(1)
    except:
        galx = ''.join(e for e in content if e.isalnum()) # Remove special characters (leaving only letters & numbers)
        galx = galx[galx.index("GALX"):] # Grab everything from GALX forward
        galx = galx[:galx.index("input")] # Truncate at input (first word after GALX value)
        galx = galx[galx.index("value")+5:] # Extract GALX value
```