# Python- Google voice

Tags: python, macos, file, google-voice

I am trying to use http://sphinxdoc.github.io/pygooglevoice/examples.html#send-sms-messages and I am getting the error

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/googlevoice/voice.py", line 72, in login
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My code is:

```
from googlevoice import Voice
from googlevoice.util import input
import sys

username, password = "email@gmail.com", "password"
voice = Voice()
voice.login(username, password)

phoneNumber = input('Number to send message to: ')
text = input('Message text: ')

voice.send_sms(phoneNumber, text)
```

I was wondering if that is a login error or error in the code? If so, how can I edit the code so that it works?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I have been researching this and apparently it's a common problem and I have to change line 72 in the file voice.py but I can't find the file:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlevoice/voice.py
```

To install, I did:

```
$ pip install python python-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install simplejson
$ sudo easy_install -U pygooglevoice
```

And now I can't find the voice.py file. I have been looking for a while on my mac but found nothing.

Other questions with the same problem:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/pygooglevoice/issues/76
[googlevoice will not programatically login (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661031/googlevoice-will-not-programatically-login-python?rq=1)
[python: pygooglevoice unable to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376472/python-pygooglevoice-unable-to-login?rq=1)

Please please please help!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling through errors and replacing the one line (which never worked...) I downloaded https://github.com/pettazz/pygooglevoice and put the googlevoice file in the same file I was working on. Hope this helps anyone with the same question.